# JSON_VALUE with square-bracket terminated JSON object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a JSON field terminated by the square brackets.  It's in valid JSON format validated by https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
[
   {
      "billId":"1111",
      "memberId":"2222",
      "patientId":"3333",
      "details":[
         {
            "itemNumber":"A.111",
            "quantity":1,
            "unitPrice":1.11,
            "priceList":null,
            "location":"2",
            "uom":"each"
         },
         {
            "itemNumber":"A.11",
            "quantity":1,
            "unitPrice":1.11,
            "priceList":null,
            "location":"2",
            "uom":"Each"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The JSON_VALUE function seems to have a problem parsing this object refusing to cooperate with me until I remove the terminating square brackets using something quite crude like `right(LEFT(JsonBody,len(JsonBody)-1),len(JsonBody)-2) as Json` and than it's happy to work returning what I expect from a command like `SELECT JSON_VALUE (Json,'$.billId')`.

What would be a better way of handling this situation - is there a switch, an option for the JSON_VALUE (which I have overlooked) which allows it to handle JSON objects formatted in the manner above or some other more elegant way of dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets denote an array with a single element so you need to use the array access syntax to select the first (and only) element.

```
'$[0].billId'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dd1fd142a058c92958ac6341a75fc5e)